# i added tabs but views outside tabs became unreachable (ios)

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, tabs

my original app had 5 home screen views and buttons in the home screens would open different other views.

i am not using storyboards. orignally there were no tabs in the app. then i added tabs to display the home screen using

```
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil] ;
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController3 = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController4 = [[FourthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FourthViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController5 = [[FifthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FifthViewController" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *navigationController1=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController1];
    [navigationController1.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"upwhitebg.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    UINavigationController *navigationController2=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController2];
    [navigationController2.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"upwhitebg.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    UINavigationController *navigationController3=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController3];
    [navigationController3.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"upwhitebg.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    UINavigationController *navigationController4=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController4];
    [navigationController4.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"upwhitebg.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    UINavigationController *navigationController5=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController5];
    [navigationController5.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"upwhitebg.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];


     UITabBarController *tabBarController= [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    tabBarController.viewControllers = @[navigationController1, navigationController2,navigationController3,navigationController4,navigationController5];
        //self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;

    UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window;
    [window addSubview:tabBarController.view]

;
```

but now when i click the buttons on the homescreen how do i show the views which are outside the tabs ? and how do i comeback from that view to the 5 homescreen tab view.

earlier i was using this code to show the views on button press

```
 listController = [[MenuListController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuListController" bundle:nil];
    SUP101AppDelegate *delegate6 = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [delegate6.navController pushViewController:listController animated:YES]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can launch other viewControllers by simply presenting them on the `tabController` now.

```
listController = [[MenuListController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuListController" bundle:nil];
SUP101AppDelegate *delegate6 = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[self.tabBarController presentViewController:listController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

you should also set the tabController to be window RootViewController

```
self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
//[window addSubview:tabBarController.view]
```

Comment: Just to add a little more on this, when you set the root view controller to be your tab bar, you won't need to add the tab bar view as a subview of the window.